# Remaning characters textarea problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing the following problem: I have to calculate the remaining characters in a textarea. It is a simple task and there's a lot of reference for doing such things. The piece of code I created to do this is bellow. Everything works fine an so, but, the QA team did this: they cut and pasted a piece of text of a txt document and they pasted till they reached the maximum of text allowed in my textarea. But what happens is that even when the max of characters is not reached the user cant type anymore.

And also if I erase some characters using the backspace I cant type anymore.

Let me be more specific. Let's say that the last word is "nerd" and the remaining characters is "47". The code doesn't allow me to write more and even if I use the backspace and have "ner" I cant type a single more letter!

The fiddle bellow has the scenario to check what I am saying. You can paste the text that is in the comment of the html section of my fiddle to state what I am talking about. Thanks in advance for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/sLr8co1n/4/
GIF: http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2015020423hlKs7Ki7knoQBCZAoSaQNN&file=output_rwGbzN.gif

```
$("#textAreaComplemento").bind("keyup change", function (e) {
   calculaCaracteresRestantes();
});
var text_max = 200;
function calculaCaracteresRestantes() {
 if ($('#textAreaComplemento').val() == undefined) {
    return false;
 }

var text_length = $('#textAreaComplemento').val().length;
var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
$('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining);

  return true;
 }
```

Comment: That fiddle works perfectly...?

Comment: have you tried to copy and past the text in the comment in the html section of the fiddle till you reached the max? try it please

Comment: yes copy and pasted until reached max chars and it still functions correctly.

Comment: which browser you're using? Are you using chrome? o.O

Comment: yes I use chrome, and I have also checked it in Firefox, and IE 11

Comment: Did the solution help you resolve the issue?

Comment: hi, @saurabhrajpal I havent tried your solution yet. But I think it is going to work. As soon as I apply it I'll let you know and choose your answer as the best! Thanks for helping.

Comment: Cool.. Was just curious to check if you needed any other help if this didn't work out for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing and playing around in Fiddle, I could figure out that basically the line "$('#textAreaComplemento').val().length" is finding out the number of characters only (and not counting the number of spaces, like in this case there are 4 spaces before return false ). Hence, when you copy, paste something (say your code which has 5 spaces in between it), then the user can enter only after deleting 6 letters which makes the total count as 194 (200-6) + 5 (spaces) + space for one letter to be entered.
You can probably use something like this to avoid any spaces or carriage returns being counted by the browser and just consider the letters:

```
$(function () {
$('#test').keyup(function () {
    var x = $('#test').val();

    var newLines = x.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g);
    var addition = 0;
    if (newLines != null) {
        addition = newLines.length;
    }

    $('#length').html(x.length + addition);
})
```

})

Comment: You may want to refer to " http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/textarea.html " for more information about How to limit the number of characters entered in a textarea. Also do note that most browsers calculate the carriage returns as two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help u mate.. :)

```
  $("#textAreaComplemento").bind("keyup change input propertychange", function (e) {
        calculaCaracteresRestantes();
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpsbr48q/)

Comment: It happens the same problem, @outlooker. Try to copy and past the code in the comment of the hmtl section till the max and you'll check what I mean. thanks for the help.

Comment: It works fine to me.The character limit reduces when we mouse click paste a text.

Comment: I simulated the problem in four more diferent computers in my company and the poblem happens. =/ I dont know if I am not being clear enough

Comment: Seriously mate,I can't find any problems.Did u check the fiddle or u used this code and checked it in your project..??

Comment: yeap! With four more other people, I used their computer to check.

Comment: No, there are no errors:
http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2015020423hlKs7Ki7knoQBCZAoSaQNN&file=output_rwGbzN.gif